# Intersystems Cache - Using Cache Server Page (Intersystems) to call ASHX through javascript

Tags: asp.net, ihttphandler, intersystems-cache

I am using Cache Server Page (Intersystems) and trying to call ASHX through javascript, but it doesn't work.

How do I call ashx written in c# in cache server pages ?

I tried to to use the following method.

Intersystems Cache

```
    Class ArithematicMean.MeanPage Extends %CSP.Page
{

ClassMethod OnPage() As %Status
{
    &html<<html id="arithematicmean">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="external_javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MeanCalculation.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<script language='javascript'>
function mean(array)
{
 var Mean = 0, N = 0, MeanPrev = 0, Sum=0, p;  
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
 {
   ++N;

   p = parseFloat(array[i]);
   if (!isNaN(p)) Sum += p;

   MeanPrev = Mean;
   Mean += (array[i] - MeanPrev) / N;
 }
 alert (Sum);
 alert(Mean ? Math.round(Mean*10)/10 : 0);
}


var httpReq = null;
    function InstructionsImageASHX() 
    {


        httpReq = XMLHttpRequest();


        httpReq.open("GET", "InstructionsImage.ashx", true);
         alert('hi123');
         httpReq.onreadystatechange = XMLHttpRequestCompleted;
        httpReq.send(null);

    }

    // initialize XMLHttpRequest object
    function XMLHttpRequest() {
        var xmlHttp;
        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch (e) {
            // IEBrowsers
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

    function XMLHttpRequestCompleted()
    {
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4)
        {
            try
            {
                alert(httpReq.responseText);
            }
            catch (e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<center>
<h1> Sum and Arithemetic Mean Calculation for 3 Numbers</h1>
</center>
<table cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="20%">
</td>
<td  width="20%">
<label name="lblnumone"> Value One</label>
</td>
<td  width="20%"> 
<input type="text" name="txtnumone" id="txtnumone" runat="server" width="10"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="20%">
</td>
<td width="20%">
<label name="lblnumtwo"> Value Two</label>
</td>
<td width="20%"> 
<input type="text" name="txtnumtwo" id="txtnumtwo"  runat="server" width="21"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="20%">
</td>
<td width="20%">
<label name="lblnumthree"> Value Three</label>
</td>
<td width="20%"> 
<input type="text" name="txtnumthree" id="txtnumthree" runat="server"  width="21"/>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="20%">
</td>
<td width="20%">
<button id="btnInstructionsImage" onclick= 'InstructionsImageASHX();'>Instructions in Image</button>
</td>
<td width="20%"> 
<button id="btnCalculate" onclick='alert( mean( [document.getElementById("txtnumone").value,document.getElementById("txtnumtwo").value,document.getElementById("txtnumthree").value] ) );'>Calculate Mean</button>
</td>
<td width="20%">
<img src="InstructionsImage.ashx" height="100" width="200">
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>>
    Quit $$$OK
}

}
```

Comment: CSP pretty much fills the same architectural role as asp.net.  So, are you using both?  I don't actually see any sign you are using CSP in your example.

Comment: CSP dosen't have much code.
I want to generate text in png, doc and pdf format and I wanted to use ASHX for each of these. For example, if we click a button for png then the text is shown in png format etc, respectively.

Comment: So  you have some CSP pages serve up some entirely static HTML files and then you want to use javascript to call to an ASHX page in asp.net?  If so you can probably remove the cache and csp tags since all they do is serve a static file.  Assuming you have your web server set up with both CSP and asp.net and aren't under the impression that CSP can somehow directly handle ASHX files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to call `ASHX` from a client side `JavaScript`.

If so, it is no `CSP` problem at all. The page could be generated by `JSP` or `PHP` with the same result, a `HTML` page. The problem probably lies somewhere in your `JavaScript` code. Try some tutorials on `ASHX`, or find some ready-made `AJAX` solution.

Since it's a `CSP` page, it doesn't have to be static. You should better use some `Caché ObjectScript` code to generate repeated code and insert some content from the database. For example:

```
for i=1:1:3 {
    &html< 
        <tr>
            <td><label>Value no.#(i)#</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="value#(i)#" id="value#(i)"></td>
        </tr>
    >
}
```

This generates three rows with *`Value no.1`* to *`Value no.3`* labels.